# Show that, for any invertible $n \times n$ real matrix $A$, there exists $c>0$ so that for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n},\|A v\| \geq c\|v\|$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

1) Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a matrix with nonzero determinant. Show that there exists $c>0$ so that for every $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n},\|A v\| \geq c\|v\|$

My attempt:
Since $A$ is invertible, we have $\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}>0$ for all $v \neq 0$. But how can we fix a constant $c>0$ ?

Comment: Do you have access to the eigenvalue decomposition? Do you know, what it does and how to use it in this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Observe
\begin{align}
\|A^{-1}x\| \leq C\|x\|.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The set $\{ v : \| v \| = 1\}$ is compact and $v \mapsto \|A v\|$ is continuous.